# Overflow:hidden dots at the end

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a string "**I like big butts and I cannot lie**" and I cut it with `overflow:hidden`, so it displays something like this:

> I like big butts and I cann

cutting off the text. Is it possible to display this like this:

> I like big butts and I cann...

using CSS?

Comment: Is this question a ruse to promote the song?

Comment: @CyrilGupta Sorry for the late response. I had to run to the bathroom. To answer your question... Yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show dots ("...") in a span with hidden overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426275/how-can-i-show-dots-in-a-span-with-hidden-overflow)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate, there are no butts involved in that one.

Answer (score 536):

You can use [text-overflow: ellipsis;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow) which [according to caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow) is supported by all the major browsers.

Here's [a demo](http://jsbin.com/eduten/2) on jsbin.

```css
.cut-text { 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 160px; 
  height: 1.2em; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="cut-text">
I like big butts and I can not lie.
</div>
```

Comment: This seemed to work in Firefox 15.0.1: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

Comment: Yes, it appears to work in newer versions. Obviously this answer is a few years old at this point.

Comment: Firefox started to support this as of version 7, which was released in the latter half of 2011.

Comment: I can use my common sense to tell that this answer is "right" based on the votes and comments. However, I fail to see in reality how this answer is "right". I used both `overflow: hidden;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in a `<p>` element (i.e., a block element) and found no `...` at the end (of course I am making sure that it is indeed overflowing). I also tried this without the `overflow: hidden;` part, and also with a `<span>` element inside the `<p>` element where the `<p>` element had `overflow: hidden;` and the `<span>` had `text-overflow: ellipsis;` No matter how I try, this is a fail..

Comment: BTW, I tried this in Chrome, and while I am getting that this rule at least used to have compatibility issues, I would certainly expect it to work in the most recent version of Chrome as of `7/23/2013`. What am I doing wrong? This seems too easy to mess up, LOL.

Comment: Well, I think I know the problem. I am trying to restrict the overflow based on `max-height` so I cannot have `white-space:` set to `nowrap`

Comment: @JoePhillips is there any to place more after dots like "hi, this is s... more" when clicking on more to show the full text

Comment: @NunnaS No clue. Good question. Probably worthy of a separate stackoverflow question

Comment: Anyone know how to change just the 3 dots color without change the text color?

Comment: @m3h0w Correct. I believe you have to specify a static width

Comment: in my case, I also needed to add width: 100% to the block.

Answer (score 117):

Check the following snippet for your problem

```css
div{
  width : 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
    The Alsos Mission was an Allied unit formed to investigate Axis scientific developments, especially nuclear, chemical and biological weapons, as part of the Manhattan Project during World War II. Colonel Boris Pash, a former Manhattan P
</div>
```

Comment: up's for adding "white-space: nowrap;" which might be needed in some cases

Comment: how to make the text to display 2 lines then disappear?

Comment: @Matian2040 you can adjust by giving fixed height and overflow hidden styles, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5135L4bx/

Comment: oh i see. i tried. however it seems two lines means there won't be a ... at the end?

Comment: is their any solution if I want to make tow lines and in the second line these dots  to be shown

Comment: `display: inline-block;` was the missing component for me. Thank you.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` was missing for me, thank you @Arjun and @leo

Comment: What specifically solved my problem:   white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score 46):

Try this if you want to restrict the lines up to 3 and after three lines the dots will appear. If we want to increase the lines just change the -webkit-line-clamp value and give the width for div size.

```
div {
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: apologies, Im not sure how i removed your words like that!

Comment: works great on Chrome, but note that this will not work on Firefox

Comment: How do I do this on another browser, say Firefox? Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 29):

Hopefully it's helpful for you:

```css
.text-with-dots {
    display: block;
    max-width: 98%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class='text-with-dots'>Some texts here Some texts here Some texts here Some texts here Some texts here Some texts here </div>
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

**Hide text on load and show on hover**

```css
.hide-text {
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

span:hover {
   white-space: unset;
   text-overflow: unset;
}
```

```html
<span class="hide-text"> How to hide text by dots and show text on hover</span>
```

Answer (score 15):

Yes, via the [`text-overflow`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) property in CSS 3. Caveat: it is not universally supported yet in browsers.

Comment: Browser support is pretty darn good now, as of Feb 2012.  See http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow

Comment: Ah, you're the reason this question showed up three years later.

Answer (score 12):

In **[bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow)**, you can add a `.text-truncate` class to truncate the text with an ellipsis.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Inline level -->
<span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 190px;">
  I like big butts and I cannot lie
</span>
```

Answer (score 12):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.cardDetaileclips{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3; /* after 3 line show ... */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100px;">
  <div class="cardDetaileclips">
    My Name is Manoj and pleasure to help you.
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<style>
    .dots
    {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 325px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

    .dot
    {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 185px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
.cut-text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Add an explanation as to why your answer is better than the 10 others

Comment: @ZachJensz Brother, Almost all other answers are also correct, but my focus is to first solve the problem and this is the code that does the actual job! no other styling, formatting, spacing.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't need the `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 5):

Most of solutions use static width here. But it can be sometimes wrong for some reasons.

Example: I had table with many columns. Most of them are narrow (static width). But the main column should be as wide as possible (depends on screen size).

HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 60px;">narrow</td>
    <td>
      <span class="cutwrap" data-cutwrap="dynamic column can have really long text which can be wrapped on two rows, but we just need not wrapped texts using as much space as possible">
        dynamic column can have really long text which can be wrapped on two rows
        but we just need not wrapped texts using as much space as possible
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.cutwrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  white-space: normal;
  color: transparent !important;
}
.cutwrap::selection {
  color: transparent !important;
}
.cutwrap:before {
  content: attr(data-cutwrap);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #333;
}
/* different styles for links */
a.cutwrap:before {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #05c;
}
```

Comment: Related to [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44452722/14928633)