# CSS text-overflow in a table cell?

Tags: css, overflow

I want to use CSS `text-overflow` in a table cell, such that if the text is too long to fit on one line, it will clip with an ellipsis instead of wrapping to multiple lines. Is this possible?

I tried this:

```
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But the `white-space: nowrap` seems to make the text (and its cell) continually expand out to the right, pushing the total width of the table beyond the width of its container. Without it, however, the text continues to wrap to multiple lines when it hits the edge of the cell.

Comment: Table cells don't handle `overflow` well. Try putting a div in the cell and styling that div.

Answer (score 1175, accepted):

To clip text with an ellipsis when it overflows a table cell, you will need to set the `max-width` CSS property on each `td` class for the overflow to work. No extra layout `div` elements are required:

```
td
{
 max-width: 100px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

For responsive layouts; use the `max-width` CSS property to specify the effective minimum width of the column, or just use `max-width: 0;` for unlimited flexibility. Also, the containing table will need a specific width, typically `width: 100%;`, and the columns will typically have their width set as percentage of the total width

```
table {width: 100%;}
td
{
 max-width: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
td.column_a {width: 30%;}
td.column_b {width: 70%;}
```

Historical: For IE 9 (or less) you need to have this in your HTML, to fix an IE-specific rendering issue

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
table {table-layout: fixed; width: 100px;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: The table also needs a width for this to work in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/rBthS/69

Comment: @Trevor Dixon Thanks Trev, didn't notice that was a requirement, but is in my normal code anyway

Comment: @TFD about the IE issue, could you provide a reading link? Or explain a bit what's going on please

Comment: @Olga Old IE generally renders different from other render engines. It seems to need width property, regardless of max-width property

Comment: Also consider wrapping the contents inside the TD with a DIV tag and then apply the text flow limiting css to that DIV, this gave me the functionality I needed.

Comment: If you set `width: 100%;` and `min-width: 1px;` the cell will always be as wide as possible and will only use ellipsis to truncate the text when it needs to (not when the element width hits a certain size) - this is very useful for responsive layouts.

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric it works on `display: table-cell` indeed, but not when the `max-width` is defined in percentage (%). Tested on FF 32

Comment: (Following up on the above) in the case you use % values, then only using `table-layout: fixed` on the element with `display: table` will do the trick

Comment: To expand a little on the `<td style="width: 100%">` responsive case: remove `width: 100%`s from all cells or columns, add `table-layout: fixed; width: 100%` to the **<table>** element, then specify widths *only* to `<col>` or (first row) `<td>` elements you want to be *no wider* than that width. Have no width specified for columns that should be as wide as possible.

Comment: How about if you want the width of the columns to be assigned automatically on a responsive fashion like bootstrap responsive table? setting a max-width will intrude on that. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345158/variable-sized-column-with-ellipsis-in-a-table

can reduce max-width to 1px.

Comment: thanks a ton.. it worked like magic. I was just missing max-width:0;

Comment: Works perfectly as of January 2020 and latest version of Chrome etc.

Comment: Using fixed layout kinda goes against using tables in the first place  (plain divs or flex work just fine in that case), the answer by Olaf works while preserving fluid table behaviors and automatic width.

Comment: ATTENTION - max-width: 0; stopped working on 27-05-2021 with Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77

Comment: For variable width columns, you'd need to do something like this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I've been searching this for the last hour.

Answer (score 130):

Specifying a `max-width` or fixed width doesn't work for all situations, and the table should be fluid and auto-space its cells.  That's what tables are for. Works on IE9 and other browsers.

Use this: http://jsfiddle.net/maruxa1j/

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
.first {
    width: 50%;
}
.ellipsis {
    position: relative;
}
.ellipsis:before {
    content: '&nbsp;';
    visibility: hidden;
}
.ellipsis span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ellipsis first"><span>This Text Overflows and is too large for its cell.</span></td>
            <td class="ellipsis"><span>This Text Overflows and is too large for its cell.</span></td>
            <td class="ellipsis"><span>This Text Overflows and is too large for its cell.</span></td>
            <td class="ellipsis"><span>This Text Overflows and is too large for its cell.</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Note: this solution wraps cell contents in `<span>` elements.

Comment: This is a really clever solution, and works well for all the tables I would require a solution for. It does however require you to set widths if you don't want all the table cells to be the same width.

Comment: When there are no fixed widths, this solution works best. Very clever indeed!

Comment: This keeps the vertical alignment when other solution like `display: block` did not

Comment: "table should be fluid and auto-space its cells. That's what tables are for.". Really? Where is this rule from?

Comment: what is this `:before` used for? I tried to remove it and didn't notice any change, browser compatibility maybe?

Comment: This trick works well with `span:hover` effect to popup the full text. Just add some border, background, and let the text wrap out of the cell (`white-space: normal`).

Comment: @gogaz The `:before` sets height of the cell so that it does not collapse when there is no other cell around. Also, some borders may not be rendered for empty cells.

Comment: HTML entities like `&nbsp;` [don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content) in CSS `content` property values.

Comment: I must be missing something, although I followed this css exactly and while it does make truncating with the ellipsis work, it definitely does NOT autosize the columns (at least, not in Chrome). They still wind up being forced to equal width, so this is effectively the exact same solution as setting the table to fixed-width, only with lots more CSS.

Comment: So, to follow up, I took a look at the fiddle and there it DOES set a width (though a percentage width) on the column that gets truncated. So, "the table should be fluid and auto-space its cells" is a bit misleading imho.

Comment: The dots are not appearing with this solution, how come?

Comment: @floris click _Run Code Snippet_ above

Comment: That's an amazing solution. But I'd replace `<td class="ellipsis first"><span>...` by `<td class="first"><div class="ellipsis"><span>...`. Otherwise the cell padding is not respected.

Comment: This solution significantly reduces performance in Safari 15.

Answer (score 48):

***Why* does this happen?**

It seems [this section on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#text-overflow) suggests that *text-overflow applies only to block elements*:

```
11.1.  Overflow Ellipsis: the ‘text-overflow’ property

text-overflow      clip | ellipsis | <string>  
Initial:           clip   
APPLIES TO:        BLOCK CONTAINERS               <<<<
Inherited:         no  
Percentages:       N/A  
Media:             visual  
Computed value:    as specified
```

The [MDN says the same](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow).

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBthS/1/) has your code (with a few debug modifications), which works fine if it's applied to a `div` instead of a `td`. It also has the only workaround I could quickly think of, by wrapping the contents of the `td` in a containing `div` block. However, that looks like "ugly" markup to me, so I'm hoping someone else has a better solution. The code to test this looks like this:

```css
td, div {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
Works, but no tables anymore:
<div>Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah.</div>

Works, but non-semantic markup required:
<table><tr><td><div>Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah.</div></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I couldn't remove the table cells from my markup, so instead I just wrapped the contents in divs (with their widths set to the widths of the cells) and applied the overflow there instead. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 38):

### In case you don't want to set fixed width to anything

The solution below allows you to have table cell content that is long, but must not affect the width of the parent table, nor the height of the parent row. For example where you want to have a table with `width:100%` that still applies auto-size feature to all other cells. Useful in data grids with "Notes" or "Comment" column or something.

[image]

Add these 3 rules to your CSS:

```css
.text-overflow-dynamic-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: text-bottom !important;
}
.text-overflow-dynamic-ellipsis {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.text-overflow-dynamic-container:after,
.text-overflow-dynamic-ellipsis:after {
    content: '-';
    display: inline;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
```

Format HTML like this in any table cell you want dynamic text overflow:

```html
<td>
  <span class="text-overflow-dynamic-container">
    <span class="text-overflow-dynamic-ellipsis" title="...your text again for usability...">
      //...your long text here...
    </span>
  </span>
</td>
```

Additionally apply desired `min-width` (or none at all) to the table cell.

Of course the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9wycg99v/23/

Comment: It messes up the selected width limits of every column, e.g. if you have some columns defined for `max-width: X` they now can be wider -- I thought this is because of `display: flex` being used, but I removed that and see no difference...

Answer (score 36):

### If you just want the table to auto-layout

*Without* using `max-width`, or percentage column widths, or `table-layout: fixed` etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/tturadqq/

How it works:

---

**Step 1: Just let the table auto-layout do its thing.**

When there's one or more columns with a lot of text, it will shrink the other columns as much as possible, then wrap the text of the long columns:

[image]

---

**Step 2: Wrap cell contents in a div, then set that div to `max-height: 1.1em`**

(the extra 0.1em is for characters which render a bit below the text base, like the tail of 'g' and 'y')

[image]

---

**Step 3: Set `title` on the divs**

This is good for accessibility, and is necessary for the little trick we'll use in a moment.

[image]

---

**Step 4: Add a CSS `::after` on the div**

This is the tricky bit. We set a CSS `::after`, with `content: attr(title)`, then position that on top of the div and set `text-overflow: ellipsis`. I've coloured it red here to make it clear.

(Note how the long column now has a tailing ellipsis)

[image]

---

**Step 5: Set the colour of the div text to `transparent`**

And we're done!

[image]

Comment: Awesome, man! (@user9645 - that's not right: have it working with a table rendered with Vue.js - be sure to put the titles on the the div's, not on the td's )

Comment: @ChristianOpitz - Yep I must have messed it up somehow... retried it and it is working.

Comment: I observed that this approach fails when using `<a>` instead of `<div>` inside table cell. Adding `word-break: break-all;` solves the problem. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/de0bjmqv/

Comment: Just great. And you don't even have to have the same text in the cells (titles are enough), and then you don't need max-height: 1.1em etc - all you need for the divs is position: relative;.

Comment: I could even get a working example without the title/after trick, using just divs, by applying similar styles to them. Kjetil Hansen did the same, see his answer below.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had to also add a `white-space: normal;` to the `td div::after` css. Then it worked for what I needed wit ellipsis.

Comment: Clever solution. I learned something new about CSS `content` and `attr()` properties. However, I agree with KS74.  This solution is over-kill and over-clever. It's hard to understand why you need to set the ellipsis in the `::after`-div when it can simply be done to the `td` (or `td>div`) text itself. Remember that anything generated in the `::after` styling of CSS isn't included in the DOM, and depending on the wider context of where/how the table is being used, this may be a significant problem that needs its own work-around.

Comment: This is such an underrated answer! This solution is really clever and works especially well in a data grid scenario, where you never really need multiple lines per row. Just a minor improvement I would add is `pointer-events: none` to the `:after` pseudo element, so that you are able to select the text in the rows.

Answer (score 28):

It seems that if you specify `table-layout: fixed;` on the `table` element, then your styles for `td` should take effect. This will also affect how the cells are sized, though.

Sitepoint discusses the table-layout methods a little here:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/tableformatting

Comment: This should be the correct answer when you don't want to specify the width of the table.

Answer (score 20):

When it's in percentage table width, or you can't set fixed width on table cell. You can apply **`table-layout: fixed;`** to make it work.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah. Lorem ipsum and dim sum yeah yeah yeah.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 10):

Wrap cell content in a flex block. As a bonus, cell auto fits visible width.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

div.parent {
  display: flex;
}

div.child {
  flex: 1;
  width: 1px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </div>
      <div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I also had to add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `child` class.

Comment: This is exactly the same as all the other solutions here, in that it forces columns to equal width, disabling auto-sizing of columns.

Answer (score 8):

This worked in my case, in both Firefox and Chrome:

```css
td {
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When I did this, I got my th and td mispositioned...

Comment: This worked for me too in all browsers, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I solved this using an absolutely positioned div inside the cell (relative).

```
td {
    position: relative;
}
td > div {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;        
}
```

That's it. Then you can either add a top: value to the div or vertically center it:

```
td > div {      
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    height: 1.5em; // = line height 
}
```

To get some space on the right side, you can reduce the max-width a little.

Comment: it would be nice with a JSFiddle, as many of the other answers to this popular question.

Comment: Yep, this works, but I used a bit different styles for divs: 
left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;padding:2px;
to get the right position, and to have the same padding as in the table's cells.

Comment: This does force all columns to be equal in width, so it is the same solution as setting the table to fixed-width, just involving an extra element (div).

Answer (score 5):

It is worked for me

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## For Clean Autosized Tables with Ellipsis

If you can ditch the table tags, then modern CSS has a much cleaner (IMO) solution available: using the `grid` layout.

You simply need one `div` or similar to represent the table, with cells inside, e.g.:

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">text</div>
  <div class="cell">text</div>
  <div class="cell">text</div>
  <div class="cell">text</div>
</div>
```

Now if I want this to be a 2x2 table then it's simply a case of defining two auto sized columns for the grid:

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

For the cells you simply need a few more lines of CSS:

```
.cell {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Job done! If you need to ensure some columns are wider than others then using the `fr` units or other available options for the columns template works well.

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
.cell {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</div>
  <div class="cell">text</div>
  <div class="cell">text</div>
  <div class="cell">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r92c4b0p/

Comment: This is the only solution here that works without messing up the auto-width of table columns.

Comment: This solution requires that you know the number of columns in the table ahead of time (i.e. `grid-template-auto` property needs to define an `auto` keyword for each column in the table). If your table is dynamic and you don't know the number of columns in advance, you need to do some CSS gymnastics to make it work. One possible work-around would be to define: `.table-col-2 { grid-template-columns: auto auto; }` `.table-col-5 { grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto; }` etc. and dynamically apply the correct class in the HTML at runtime.  But it's a messy solution.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse If I didn't know the number of columns at run time I'd probably use a CSS variable for the value of `grid-template-columns` and then just set that via JS - no need for any extra classes etc. and it could default to the expected count.

Comment: @MattLacey no doubt there are clever JavaScript solutions to make the grid system work dynamically.  And for some scenarios your solution would be very elegant. All the same, I can't help but feel that in any dynamic scenario where the aim is to present data in a tabular context, CSS grids just over-engineer the problem.  Why use a solution that was designed to address a completely different problem, then have to gloss over the cracks with unnecessary JavaScript, when plain HTML already offers a simple means of presenting 2D/tabular data.

Comment: Because the standard elements don't work as desired in this specific scenario? I'd always use a table for a table where it works, but in my scenario (and what led me to this question) was  I needed a 2x2 grid with 1 to 4 cells that would truncate text in this manner

Comment: Anyone doing this (using the grid method as opposed to the classic `<table>`) should be implementing [aria-roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/table_role) for SEO & accessibility concerns.

Answer (score 1):

what worked fine for me is this simple code. By playing with number of character you can get the dots in almost any td you want

```css
table *{
    max-width: 50ch;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### XML

```
<td><div>Your overflowing content here.</div></td>
```

### CSS

```
td div
{
 max-height: 30vh;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Trying to mess with the overall `table` for this very specific purpose makes no sense. Yes, sometimes it *is* okay to add an extra element if you explicitly work to not be another 600-divs-nested Twitter/Facebook "developer".

Answer (score -7):

This is the version that works in IE 9.

http://jsfiddle.net/s27gf2n8/

```
<div style="display:table; table-layout: fixed; width:100%; " >
        <div style="display:table-row;">
            <div style="display:table-cell;">
                <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
                    <div style="text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">First row. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="display:table-cell;">
                Top right Cell.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-row;">
            <div style="display:table-cell;">
                <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
                    <div style="text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">Second row - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="display:table-cell;">
                Bottom right cell.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: a <div> as a direct child of <table> ? That doesn't seem right!

Comment: @michiel FYI -  browsers can handle Divs below table tags.

Comment: @RyanO'Connell, just because you can, doesn't mean you should... according to the HTML spec this is invalid, regardless of browsers can render it or not