# Why doesn't CSS ellipsis work in table cell?

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

Consider the following example: ([live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fd3Zx/1/))

```js
$(function() {
  console.log("width = " + $("td").width());
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello Stack Overflow</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The output is: `width = 139`, and the ellipsis doesn't appear.

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)

Comment: Somehow duplicate, but the answer doesn't provide a workaround (as Arlen Cuss does).

Comment: `width` and `height` on table cells are always used as _minimal_ width and height. Table cells are different!

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Actually, the other question does provide a workaround: put a div in the cell with the desired width.

Comment: I still prefer the answers listed on this page however.

Comment: For `text-overflow:ellipsis` to work, here are the requirements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Apparently, adding:

```
td {
  display: block; /* or inline-block */
}
```

solves the problem as well.

---

Another possible solution is to set `table-layout: fixed;` for the table, and also set it's `width`. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/fd3Zx/5/

Comment: Exactly. Elements with `display: table-cell` (the default for `td` elements) don't accept a width.

Comment: `display: block;` sort of defeats the purpose of using a table. I like the `table-layout: fixed;` option, it worked well for me.

Comment: `table-layout:fixed` distributes the width of the columns in a less smart way. Is there another option that will assign column width the same way `table-layout: normal` and yet display the ellipsis correctly?

Comment: This screws with the table border; using max-width does not.

Answer (score 93):

It's also important to put

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

Onto the containing table, so it operates well in IE9 (if your utilize max-width) as well.

Comment: this will also make sure that text overflow works in responsive layouts

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I have the table width 100%.  And all of the columns except for one with a fixed width.  This allows the last column to take up as much space as is left over.

Answer (score 85):

As said before, you can use `td { display: block; }` but this defeats the purpose of using a table.

You can use `table { table-layout: fixed; }` but maybe you want it to behave differently for some colums.

So the best way to achieve what you want would be to wrap your text in a `<div>` and apply your CSS to the `<div>` (not to the `<td>`) like this :

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td > div {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest method I've seen and it actually works in IE8.

Comment: THAT is actually the best solution I've seen on ellipsis in tables.

Comment: I'm not clear on how this is any different, since it forces the definition of a width. It still completely disables table column auto-sizing, which means you now have to fiddle with pixel nudging on every column in your entire app. For a large app this is a nightmare.

Answer (score 46):

Try using `max-width` instead of `width`, the table will still calculate the width automatically.

Works even in `ie11` (with ie8 compatibility mode).

```css
td.max-width-50 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="max-width-50">Hello Stack Overflow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello Stack Overflow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello Stack Overflow</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fd3Zx/2/).

Comment: Well spotted. It is probably best to use *both*, so that the element is a fixed width. Otherwise it could be shorter if the contents allowed it.

Comment: Way better than display hack; displayhack screws with the table border.

Answer (score 27):

### [Demo page](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/QNxeVQ)

For tables with dynamic width, I found the below way to produce satisfying results. Each `<th>` which is wished to have trimmed-text ability should have an inner wrapping element which wraps the contents of the `<th>` allow [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to work.

> The real trick is to set `max-width` (on the `<th>`) in **[`vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) units**.

This will effectively cause the element's width to be "bound" to the viewport width (browser window) and will result in a responsive content clipping. Set the `vw` units to a satisfying value needed.

#### Minimal CSS:

```
th{ max-width:10vw; }
      
th > .wrap{ 
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
   overflow:hidden;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

---

#### Demo (with editable texts):

```js
document.designMode="on"
```

```css
table {
  font: 18px Arial;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.4);
}

table td, table th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.2em 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.4);
}

table td:first-child, table th:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

table th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.4);
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: 10vw;
}

table th > .wrap {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="wrap" title="Some long title">Some long title</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="wrap">Short</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="wrap">medium one</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="wrap" title="endlessly super long title which no developer likes to see">endlessly super long title which no developer likes to see</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>very long text here</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure how this ``vw`` unit works, but the result is just perfect, because the table keeps auto-sizing columns normally with this method.

Answer (score 3):

Just offering an alternative as I had this problem and none of the other answers here had the desired effect I wanted. So instead I used a list. Now semantically the information I was outputting could have been regarded as both tabular data but also listed data.

So in the end what I did was:

```
<ul>
    <li class="group">
        <span class="title">...</span>
        <span class="description">...</span>
        <span class="mp3-player">...</span>
        <span class="download">...</span>
        <span class="shortlist">...</span>
    </li>
    <!-- looped <li> -->
</ul>
```

So basically `ul` is `table`, `li` is `tr`, and `span` is `td`.

Then in CSS I set the `span` elements to be `display:block;` and `float:left;` (I prefer that combination to `inline-block` as it'll work in older versions of IE, to clear the float effect see: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) and to also have the ellipses:

```
span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;

    // truncate when long
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then all you do is set the `max-widths` of your spans and that'll give the list an appearance of a table.

Comment: can you apply ul inside td (eg. `<td><ul>...</ul></td>`)? It doesn't seems to work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ellipsis to solve the problem of overflowing text, I found that a disabled and styled input looked better and still allows the user to view and select the entire string if they need to.

```
<input disabled='disabled' style="border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0" />
```

It looks like a text field but is highlight-able so more user friendly

Comment: It is not user friendly because using assistive tecnologies this gets mis-read as an input and so the user thinks he can input something. It is quite not ok to misuse the semantics of the elements.

Comment: OMG, this is so clever! since it is part of the table, just simply set the input as borderless with transparent background. I love this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Check `box-sizing` css property of your `td` elements. I had problem with css template which sets it to `border-box` value. You need set `box-sizing: content-box`.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many of the above solutions but none of them felt flexible or satisfying.

This little hack with max-width: 1px can be applied directly to the td element

```
.truncated-cell {
   max-width: 1px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

Comment: This seems to do the same exact thing as setting the table to fixed-width, which is that it forces all columns to an equal width rather than providing the benefit of a table's auto-width capabilities. That leaves us having to manually set widths on every single table in an application, which is tedious and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Leave your tables as they are. Just wrap the content inside the TD's with a span that has the truncation CSS applied.

```
/* CSS */
.truncate {
    width: 50px; /*your fixed width */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block; /* this fixes your issue */
}

<!-- HTML -->
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="truncate">
                    Table data to be truncated if it's too long.
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work on DataTables.net. any idea?

Comment: This is basically the same as the fixed-width solution, in that it disabled dynamic auto-sizing of columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

The above setting worked for me, without changing table widths. I added a div inside  and added the class ellipsis to it.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to set max-width to td (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372381/1691517)), you can set max-width to div:

```
function so_hack(){}
```

`function so_hack(){}` http://jsfiddle.net/fd3Zx/754/ `function so_hack(){}`

```
function so_hack(){}
```

Note: 100% doesn't work, but 99% does the trick in FF. Other modern browsers doesn't need silly div hacks.

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
td>div{
    max-width: 99%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
```