# CSS(3)-way of a table with mixed width columns?

Tags: css, css-float, css-tables

What would be CSS(3)-only way of making a table, that has mixture of fluid, content based and fixed width columns? Don't really care of supporting old browsers, IE9+ would be fine.

```
+----------------------+------+---------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Content width column | 50xp | <-- Fluid --> | 20px | Content width column | Content width column |
+----------------------+------+---------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Fluid column is expected to have `text-overflow: ellipsis` property.

Or it's not even possible? What would be an alternative to tables? Floats?

The problem I'm getting is that I need to specify width of "content based column", and it applies the width property, which is lower than content: http://plnkr.co/edit/rqrpb8oMFDDyogXSon6y?p=preview

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372369/why-doesnt-css-ellipsis-work-in-table-cell

Comment: how many "rows" do you have?

Comment: @TimSPQR, 1 row actually. But amount of columns is dynamic.

Comment: You might try an unnumbered list with  display: inline

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply `text-overflow: ellipsis` to a table cell, I had to specify it explicitly at that cell along with `max-width: 0`.

The plunk is there: http://plnkr.co/edit/rqrpb8oMFDDyogXSon6y

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw this out as an idea - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7N4Dw/).

CSS

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.content {
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.spacer50 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
}
.spacer20 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
}

.fluidme {
    width: 20%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But it wraps into multiple lines, which I need to avoid. And problem with that approach, you still have to specify percentage for the width. While I have to drop some elements into table and expect them to be wrapped as intended without knowing/specifying their geometry.

Comment: Then based on those critera, it looks like "a table it must be".