# CSS text-overflow: ellipsis in Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a Table

```
<table class="tbl" border="1">   
    <tr>
        <td width="20%"><span class="spn">column one is a long one</span></td>
        <td width="60%"><span class="spn">column two</span></td>
        <td width="20%"><span class="spn">column three is the longest of all columns</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and CSS-Settings:

```
.spn
{
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: inherit;
  color: red;    
}

.tbl
{
  width: 300px
}
```

I want the first and third column to be 20% width and the second should be 60% of the 300px table width. The text should be fill the full td and end with `...` at the end. How to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/8jgmnyn5/

Comment: What about using jquery or javascript? In this way it is not that hard to solve. Or you want to achieve this with pure css?

Comment: @d_z90 - css only if possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't CSS ellipsis work in table cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372369/why-doesnt-css-ellipsis-work-in-table-cell)

Comment: @ChrisSpittles Not a duplicate. This user has already solved the problem of the ellipsis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. For the table, you'll need `table-layout:fixed`. Otherwise it will prioritise displaying all the contents over the given column widths.
2. The spans have `width:inherit`, but the table columns have widths like 20%, so the spans will be 20% of 20%, which I'm sure is not what you meant. So get rid of the `width` on the spans. `display:block` type elements don't need widths.

```css
.spn {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /*width: inherit;*/
  color: red;    
}

.tbl
{
  width: 300px;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Then the result will look like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8jgmnyn5/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/8jgmnyn5/2/

your altered css looks like this:

```
.spn {
  display: block;
  color: red;    
}

.spn:after {
    content: "…";
}
```

Comment: almost, i want to avoid newline with `white-space: nowrap;` - the text can be cut off when it doesn't fit