# Resize an HTML Table Forcing All Columns to Stay in View

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm looking for a simple solution to having a table be able to shrink horizontally while keeping all of the columns in view. As the columns shrink the content inside of them should become horizontally scrollable.

Example problem:

http://codepen.io/kirkouimet/pen/jybbxK

Assumptions and goals:

- We will not know how many columns there will be
- The columns will always stay on one line (CSS white-space: nowrap)
- Ideally the solution does not involve JavaScript, just CSS
- It would be awesome if the text inside of the table ellipsed (...) and then when you hovered over it, it expanded and you could scroll it horizontally

Code from the Codepen link:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>First First First</th>
        <th>Second Second Second</th>
        <th>Third Third Third</th>
        <th>Fourth Fourth Fourth</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>First First First</td>
        <td>Second Second Second</td>
        <td>Third Third Third</td>
        <td>Fourth Fourth Fourth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First First First</td>
        <td>Second Second Second</td>
        <td>Third Third Third</td>
        <td>Fourth Fourth Fourth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First First First</td>
        <td>Second Second Second</td>
        <td>Third Third Third</td>
        <td>Fourth Fourth Fourth</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36766603/367865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following CSS changes will:

- Keep the text in each cell on a single line
- Show an ellipsis when the content of a cell is wider than the cell
- When hovered, the ellipsis will disappear and the content becomes scrollable

The important CSS properties are:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th:hover,
td:hover {
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

Here's an example, though the layout of SO doesn't showcase the scrolling feature due to the width. For a working example, see this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/oBjbbB) demo and resize your screen until the table cells become too narrow to show the content.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
th:hover,
td:hover {
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>First First First First First</th>
    <th>Second Second Second Second Second</th>
    <th>Third Third Third Third Third</th>
    <th>Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>First First First First</td>
    <td>Second Second Second Second</td>
    <td>Third Third Third Third Third</td>
    <td>Fourth Fourth Fourth</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First First First First</td>
    <td>Second Second Second Second</td>
    <td>Third Third Third Third Third</td>
    <td>Fourth Fourth Fourth</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First First First First</td>
    <td>Second Second Second Second</td>
    <td>Third Third Third Third Third</td>
    <td>Fourth Fourth Fourth</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Maybe use overflow-x instead of just overflow to get rid of those extra arrows.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

> **Added ellipsis to the cell with red text. Click it to read more and click it again to retract back.**

For the retracting ellipsis I used 2 `:target`s.

Scrollable, I missed that the first read, ok that's more realistic. Designed for four columns, it would be ridiculous to expect a multitude of columns given the constraints. If I have more time I'll add ellipsis, but for now, just small shrinking font will have to do. Scrolling horizontal cells are done by using `overflow:scroll/auto` on the `<td>` and append a `<div>` inside each `<td>`

**Relevant CSS**

```
table {
  width: 98vw;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
th,
td {
  font-size: .4em;
  max-width:19%;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 96vw;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: .4em;
  min-width: 19%;
}
td {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
td div {
  min-height: 30px;
}
.ell {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}
.ell::after {
  content: '&#hellip;';
  color: transparent;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
#ex1:target {
  min-width: 250ch;
  transition: all 1s;
  text-overflow: visible;
  overflow-x: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 0 none transparent;
}
a {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.in {
  display: none;
}
#ex1:target .ex {
  display: none;
}
#ex1:target .in {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>First First First</th>
    <th>Second Second Second</th>
    <th>Third Third Third</th>
    <th>Fourth Fourth Fourth</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>First First First</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Second Second Second</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>START Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third
          Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third
          Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third
          Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third
          Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third
          Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third Third END</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Fourth Fourth Fourth</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>First First First</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>START Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second
          Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second
          Second Second Second Second Second Second END</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Third Third Third</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Fourth Fourth Fourth</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>First First First</div>
      </td>

      <td id='ex1'>
        <div class='ell'>
          <a href='#ex1' class='ex'></a>
          <a href='#in1' class='in'></a>
          Second Second SecondSecond Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Third Third Third</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <p>Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth Fourth</p>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```