# CSS overflow with html <td>

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-tables

I am making a table which can have cells with long strings.  To make things fit I am trying to use the `overflow:hidden` and `overflow-text:ellipse` styles to hide the long texts. At first I was thinking I was doing something wrong, but now I am noticing that none of the overflow features work with any table elements, but work just as expected with `<div>` elements. I've worked mostly around this by placing a `<div>` in each cell, but this is awkward...

Is there a way to get overflow to work with `<td>` elements, or do I need to put `<div>` elements in my td's to get them to work with overflow?

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffpkamp/yc076du3/6/) is a JSfiddle showing tables with and without division around or within the elements giving the desired behavior as well as a table without divisions showing what I am talking about.

Comment: Perhaps post a live demo of your issue and/or check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372369/why-doesnt-css-ellipsis-work-in-table-cell

Comment: The solutions you can take are mentioned in the above SO page

Comment: I tried all of the examples in the referred question and none of them worked. I'm avoiding fixed width because I am trying to keep it adjustable.  I put an example in that you can play with showing what works and doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above

```
table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

should solve the problem but I guess it doesn't for you if you don't want the table elements to wrap.

I read up on `resize` and noted they are not very suitable for tables:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

However, when using a `fixed` table-layout this problem seems to be resolved.

The closest I could get to a solution for you was this:

https://jsfiddle.net/yc076du3/64/

However the problems with this:

1. The `resize` doesn't work unless I apply the fixed table layout as explained above.
2. I had to use a max-width for cells so they don't get too long.

I would say my answer here isn't really a final answer to your question, but some research to say that your current solution seems to work the best, unless you use workarounds like a fixed table layout but you then deal with automatic cell widths (another set of issues that doesn't match your "working" div layout).

I hope this helps. Please share if you find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

**For you** https://jsfiddle.net/yc076du3/22/

```
table{
   table-layout: fixed;
}
```

---

If u try understand how it's work...

read this: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-tables-3/#table-layout-algorithm

and this: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-tables-3/#style-overrides

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to enclose all your `<td>` elements in one `div`?

```
<div>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</div>
```

Maybe this works for you.

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work.  `<div>`s need to be inside the `<td>`.