# How to truncate a long text field and fix column width in DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I have a column in my `DataTable` that is a text field currently wrapped to multiple lines. I want to create a `DataTable` with the following properties:

- The text of each record takes one row (no wrapping)
- The columns are each a fixed length (variable by column)
- No side scrolling (`scrollX: false`)
- Overflowing text is replaced with an ellipsis `...`

I've tried modifying the css as such, but the columns expand beyond the pixel width I've defined to be as wide as possible and no text is truncated with `...`

```
th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372369/why-doesnt-css-ellipsis-work-in-table-cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)

Comment: Have you read this: https://datatables.net/blog/2016-02-26

Comment: I had to set the `max-width` property then it worked.