# text-overflow ellipsis implementation in width 100% element

Tags: html, css, responsive

I faced one CSS issue while implementing `text-overflow: ellipsis` in dynamic width like `width: 100%` according to the device sizes. (Mobile responsive especially)

**HTML**:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="text">
        This is what I want to show by using ellipsis. This is what I want to show by using 
        ellipsis. This is what I want to show by using ellipsis
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
.text {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* width: 100%; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I have spent a couple of hours to find out the solution on StackOverflow but I couldn't figure out how I can implement `p` tag has full width that is the same width as table width while showing *...* by truncating the part over the width in one line.
Here is the relevant image that I want finally.

[image]

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevindev725/3oh4gca5/10/) link
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372369/why-doesnt-css-ellipsis-work-in-table-cell

Comment: @Will, Thank you for commenting.
It works if I set `width: 100px or 200 px` by using a specific amount of width, but what I want is set width according to the table size thus I think I should use `width: 100%`.
In this case, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give `width:100%` width and  `table-layout:fixed` to your table like this below

```
.table {
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.text {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* width: 100%; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

your table will start taking width of its parent.

is this you want ?

check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vsct30a/) here