# table alignment is going wrong with text-overflow:ellipsis property

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)

I am applying td width's with css. Here when i apply css property text-overflow:ellipsis, alignment of td's going wrong.

Can any body please give me a solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/2T8pY/

Comment: text-overflow won't work with td, check this [identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9789723/944681) for more suggestions, like adding max-width to your cells..

Comment: I've done it with `tr { width: 500px; display: block; }`, but I really consider it a hack. )