# Max-Width solution in IE9 (with text-overflow)

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, css, datatables

I'm trying to use a max-width property in IE9. It is being used on a tablecell with a dynamically generated width (I'm using dataTables). I also am using "text-overflow:ellipsis;" so that it basically has the effect of cutting off the characters visually, but I cannot do this without a max-width.

I don't want to define a set width on each table cell, as the dynamically created ones work just fine in every other case.

Here is my CSS:

```
.tableViewer tbody tr td {
max-width:220px;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
 color: #000000;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
border-left: 1px solid #fff;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
/*border-bottom:  1px solid #D8D8D8; */
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

The HTML, as said before is generated via DataTables. But here is it in it's rendered form:

```
<tr class="odd">
<td class=" sorting_1" title="aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbb@aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbb.com" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; ">aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbb@aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbb.com</td>
<td class="" title="aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbb" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; ">aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbb</td><td class="" title="aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbb" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; ">aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbb</td>
<td class="" title="" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; "></td><td class="" title="" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; "></td>
<td class="" title="" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; "></td><td class="" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; ">2 <a href="#">view</a></td></tr>
```

Sorry for the long titles, but that's why I'm trying to figure this out. Anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT**:

Upon request, here's a JSfiddle showing the CSS/HTML and the problem! http://jsfiddle.net/PY4cb/

Comment: I use `text-overflow: ellipsis` without setting a `max-width` and it works just fine... the only thing really different about my css from yours is that I also use `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: What's the function of white-space:nowrap? I've added and come up with nothing in IE9.

Comment: [here's the MDN page on white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space) Could you create a jsFiddle that replicates your problem?

Comment: No problem, adding it now to the question!

Comment: Just added it, hope it helps!

Comment: Great `white-space` article: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/

Comment: Checked out the article -- it is pretty awesome, but I tried some solutions from it and it's helping me with this particular issue. Is there anyway you could look at the JSfiddle?

Comment: @MrOBrian -- I keep testing the solution to no avail. Have you ever seen anything like this before?

Comment: Anyone out there? Please help if you can!

Comment: check out [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell) to see if anything in there helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out the answer (thanks to some pointers from @MrOBrian) -- the containing table **needs** to have this attribute:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

In only IE. IE, for some reason or another, won't accept max-width in cells in a table that doesn't have this element (while all other browsers can).