# Format text inside a column

Tags: html, text, formatting

In my HTML table, the width of a column increases, when the text inside is larger than the column width. I can use overflow:hidden to keep the width in a fixed size; But i want to do something like the image bellow: 
[image]

Actual text is ( 485 - Pascal's Triangle of Death )  when it is larger than the width of a column, the text will be shown like the image. i've failed to do it manually. is there any easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a css property named ellipsis to do this...

Try this...

```
#your_element_id {

text-overflow : ellipsis;
overflow:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;

}
```

This might work...

Answer (score 1):

You can use style sheets to take care of this. You can set the `text-overflow` to `ellipsis`

There is an existing SO which demonstrates this:

[CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)