# Preventing HTML table from resizing overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have searched for this for so long but no luck.

How can I prevent an html table from re-sizing when elements (other tables ) are inside of it I want the elements to overflow from the table when necessary.

```
 table-layout:fixed;
```

The above does not work.

Comment: its not exactly clear to me what you want...are you trying to make an initial layout and overflow outside the table, or do you want it to behave like a word wrap? in that case just put an explicit `width:500px` for example...

Comment: ok the width of the table is 300 and the height is 400.

as I add other tables inside the main table the total size of the tables inside the main table add up to more than 400 instead of the table re-sizing to fit the elements inside I want them to overflow

Comment: it would be good if you posted the relevant code as well or created a jsfiddle.

Comment: Nested tables?  Smells like you're using them for layout purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell).

You can use:

```
td {
    max-width:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

EDIT: Ellipsis is optional based on what you want to do with the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/7K9jE/1/

Comment: Can this be used for the height of the table as well?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You have tables inside of tables? Is this the most efficient way to do this? It would be helpful to post come code.

Comment: this worked perfectly! I used `max-width:auto;` though