# text-overflow not working with HTML5

Tags: css, html

The following code works as desired on chrome.
But not on firefox or IE. Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag to this code, leads it not working on chrome too. Has `text-overflow` been deprecated or something? How can I make it compatible with all browsers and HTML5?

```
<head>

<style type='text/css'>
table {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 auto 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: -1;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 18%;">Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 12%;">Col 2</th>
        <th style="width: 13%;">Col 3</th>
        <th style="width: 7%">Col 4</th>
        <th style="width: 7%">Col 5</th>
        <th style="width: 6%">Col 6</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 7</th>
        <th style="width: 13%">Col 8</th>
        <th style="width: 16%">Col 9</th>
        <th style="width: 3%">Col 10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>etc</td>
        <td>whatever</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>Alotofdataikkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

This is what I want.[image]

Comment: How about this? http://jsbin.com/okuqan/2/edit

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell

Comment: it is supported by all browsers...you can check it here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misused the text-overflow property.

If you want to wrap text of an element, you have to specify the width or max-width of that element so that browsers know how to wrap the text content.

[EDITED]
This is example code:

```
<head>

<style type='text/css'>
table {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 auto 0;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    max-width: 900px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: -1;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.col1 {
  width: 80px;
}
.col7 {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.col8 {
  max-width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="col1">Col 1</th>
        <th class="col2">Col 2</th>
        <th class="col3">Col 3</th>
        <th class="col4">Col 4</th>
        <th class="col5">Col 5</th>
        <th class="col6">Col 6</th>
        <th class="col7">Col 7</th>
        <th class="col8">Col 8</th>
        <th class="col9">Col 9</th>
        <th class="col10">Col 10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Some</td>
        <td class="col2">Data</td>
        <td class="col3">Stuff</td>
        <td class="col4">foo</td>
        <td class="col5">etc</td>
        <td class="col6">whatever</td>
        <td class="col7">stuff</td>
        <td class="col8">Alotofdataikkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</td>
        <td class="col9">Yes</td>
        <td class="col10">bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Some</td>
        <td class="col2">Data</td>
        <td class="col3">Stuff</td>
        <td class="col4">foo</td>
        <td class="col5">etc</td>
        <td class="col6">whatever</td>
        <td class="col8">Alotofdataikkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</td>
        <td class="col7">stuff</td>
        <td class="col9">Yes</td>
        <td class="col10">bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Here is demo screenshot: [image]

Comment: but if I want to set max-width of all columns differently?

Comment: Use classes. Like this: .col1 { max-width: 16%;} col2 { max-width: 20%;} ... And td/th in same columns should have the same class name.

Answer (score 1):

Add max-width to your td.

```
td{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` works fine in HTML5. I think `display: block` is creating some problem. Try removing it or replace it with `display: table` and check if it works.