# Overflow text in table cell

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make text overflow in a table cell?

Like this:

```
+TABLE-----------------------------------+
| +cell1-----+ +cell2-----+ +cell3-----+ |
| |          | |          | |          | |
| |          | |Example text overflow  | |
| |          | |          | |          | |
| |          | |          | |          | |
| +----------+ +----------+ +----------+ |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I tried `overflow:visible` and `white-space:nowrap` but not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)

Comment: would colspan do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overflow the text outside the td but you need to insert a div tag like this

```
<td><div>your text goes here</div></td>
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Bvk5/1/)

Comment: It's working perfectly in FF and Chrome but not in IE 7, the text breaks in new line instead of overflowing.. How would I fix it in IE7?

Comment: Define width and height of your td div.