# CSS Break Long Text with "..."

Tags: php, css

Am trying to use `text-overflow:ellipsis` inside the `<td>` tag but it supports only to `<div>` tag.

Any idea to support for `<td>` tag?

check what am trying to do 
http://phpresult.com/source/share/L9F71379328772

Comment: You could open a new `div` inside the `td`. But I think that's a bit rubbish

Comment: Add `display: block;` and it works with `td`

Comment: @bish i dont need to do this.. any other way

Comment: If I do td {
  max-width: 100px;
} it works. It just adjusts size to fit.

Comment: @FDL, `display: block` would imply that the `td` is not rendered as a table cell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Found the Solution by using `max-width`

```
<style> 
.test
{
white-space:nowrap; 
text-overflow:ellipsis;
max-width: 100px; 
overflow:hidden; 
border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td class="test">
      This is the Long text only applied to div tag
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code...

```
td {
  display: block; /* or inline-block */
}
```

or

Use

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

or give fixed width to your table