# Make TD fit content dynamically using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, ellipsis

Here is my drama:

I have a bootstrap panel which takes 1/3 of the page (col-4-md) and inside I have a table with only tho TDs on each row (TR).

Since

1.) I want the first TD to be extended to the max width of the longest text in the first column,

2.) I would like the second column to add text-overflow:ellipsis if the containing text is very long.

One way to do the second is to add table-layout:fixed but then I couldn't find a way to to the first.

Any suggestions?

Here is a CodePen example:

codepen.io/brankoleone/pen/EyaVwY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a little bit and found one solution (tested on chrome):

1. remove `table-layout: fixed;` from `.table-crm {`
2. add `max-width: 0;` to `td + td {`
3. add `width: 1%;` and `white-space: nowrap;` to `td:first-child {`

EDIT: Heres a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5t08tota/

Comment: Perfect, it obviously works like I want to, but I can't figure out why `max-width:0;` makes it possible

Comment: I don't really know too :D just googled for "text overflow table", didn't saw any way to do it using "table-layout: fixed;" and found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell