# <a> overflow in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make a table with two columns. The first one with a text caption and second one with a link. If the link is bigger than available space than I want to overflow with "...". This is what I've tried:

```
<html>

<style>
    table {
        width: 100px;
        border: dotted;
    }

    td {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                First name and last name
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Info:
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="google.pl">CLICKKKKKKKKKKKKKKXX</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't overflow and table gets bigger than 100px. I've tried adding `max-width` to `tr{}` but it also doesn't work.

What is the solution for that?

Comment: are you sure that the inline tags behave as you expect ?

Comment: check this : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow if you change the div in a or span, it doesnt work as ellipsis

Comment: Yes, I know that but can it be done another way with `<a>`? Or can it be done with JavaScript?

Comment: put your a into a div container ? or give it 'display:inline-block'

Comment: @singebatteur but total table width will get bigger than 100px anyway...

Comment: Try putting the overflow on the a tag and give it display block I can't try these now as off to bed.

Comment: @CarolMcKay didn't work...

Comment: 'info' should be in the first row no ?

Comment: No. First row has one caption with colspan=2 and second row has two columns, "info" and a link

Comment: how about this https://jsfiddle.net/sank8893/90jrc317/

Comment: "..." do not appear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell?rq=1 did you check this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
table{table-layout:fixed;}
```

Comment: yes but beware, table-layout fixed can cause it's own problems.

Answer (score 2):

You want the **overflowing** text to be wrapped with `...` but you haven't mentioned the threshold **max-width** value to trigger overflow and replace the remaining text with `...`

Try this :

```
td
{
  width: 50px;
  max-width: 75px;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Working Example : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stgeu2e0/)

Comment: nice one! @HariHarker