# Add text-overflow: ellipsis; to table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, ellipsis

I'm having trouble containing text in a table. I want to give it a `text-overflow: ellipsis`. But I can't seem to get it to work.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="article-table">
  <thead class="article-table__headers">
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Source</th>
    <th>Abstract</th>
    <th>Folder</th>
  </thead>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr class="article-table__rows">
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.source %></td>
      <td><%= article.abstract %></td>
      <td><%= article.folder %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Download File", download_article_path(article) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.article-table td {
    width: 20%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

This isn't working though. it still increases the size of the td if text is too long

Comment: Try this:  height:24px; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need `table-layout: fixed` along with width set for the table. Otherwise ellipsis can only work with fixed `td` width. And change the value of `white-space: normal` to `nowrap`.

Looks like, your table structure also needs to be fixed, missing `<tr>` in `<thead>`, and better to add `<tbody>` below `<thead>`.

```css
.article-table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.article-table td {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table class="article-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th>Abstract</th>
      <th>Folder</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
      <td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
      <td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
      <td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I missed `table-layout: fixed;` which has been driving me nuts for the past hour. Much appreciated mate!

Comment: I think this has the same effect as the line-clamp method, but has the advantage of more efficient rendering (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#fixed)

Answer (score 3):

Placing a div inside your td tag and applying the styling to the div will achieve the text-overflow: ellipsis;  So no need to apply a fixed layout to the table.

You could also designate how many lines you want to allocate before the ... ellipsis should go into effect.

CSS

```
.max-lines-2 {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

HTML

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 25%"></th>
       <!-- add your table headers with the desired width -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td><div class="max-lines-2"></div></td>
       <!-- add your table divs with the desired width -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ellipsis do not work with: **%** (.article-table td > width: 20%; - is your problem).

My trick when I want to keep in someway "**%**" to that div, td with ellipsis is to add 2 different dimensions:

```
max-width:300px; /*Inspect element in broswer and see how many pixels is 20%*/
width: 20%;
```

In this case ellipsis working and my div, td have the dimensions I want.

And try this for .article-table td class:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```