# Limit the number of charaters in a JSF datatable column

Tags: datatable, jsf-2.2

im using JSF for J2EE projet and im looking how to limit the numbers of characters in a datatable column (h:colum; p:column).
Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks my dear, sorry for the duplicate Question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want that large text don't break in new row. My recommendation is **use css**:

```
<p:column headerText="My column" styleClass="single-line">
    <h:outputText value="#{largeTextProperty}" />
</p:column>

.single-line {
    text-wrap: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Finding 'duplicates' is good practice in Stackoverflow to prevent fragmentation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell