# How do I set the length of a string in a table to a certain length in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string-length, tailwind-css

I have a table with a title column on my index.html.erb. These titles are very long so when I render my page the table goes quite far horizontally across the screen. It's all on one line as well. 
How do I set it so that after around 6 words it goes onto another line, and after 6 more words the string is cut off. The table is looped! The full description can be read when a user visits the seperate show.html page

Some of the code below

```
<td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200">
   <div class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-900"><%= article.title %></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Characters is a much better cut off than words and will create greater consistency in the rendering. e.g. `"As one who enjoys long words"` vs `"Hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobics vehemently abhor such sesquipedalian responses"`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try counting the amount of characters that you want and limit by that, e.g

```
<%= truncate(title, length:10) %>
```

But if you need something very robust to support screen sizes etc I'm pretty sure css can help you
[CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)

Comment: Thank you! I ended up finding something in the CSS that helped yes! Cheers