# Datatable specific column data truncate not work on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, datatable, microsoft-edge

about one mouth ago, in chrome started not working my truncate function in chrome browser, but in edge it seems all good.

In chrome my datatable looks like this.
[IMG HOW DATATABLE LOOK IN CHROME IN FULL SIZE WINDOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPVDZ.png)

In edge and how i want to look it looks like this. [IMG HOW DATATABLE LOOK IN EDGE IN FULL SIZE WINDOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT2G2.png), this way looks then window smaller  [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdkQy.png)

My code
js

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true, 
        "serverSide": false,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "pageLength": 50,
        "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
        "ajax": url,
        'columnDefs': [
            { targets: 5, className:"truncate"},
 ],
        createdRow: function(row){
            var tr = $(row).find(".truncate");
            tr.attr("title", tr.html());
       }
```

css

```
  .truncate {
    max-width:50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

Any idea why this messing up in chrome browser? Then in inspect html code looks like column getting `.truncate`  class, but only rows must have it not column.

Thank you for our time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just try this way, and looks in chrome and edge working. Just set in css this code and remove yours

```
  td{
   max-width: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

more information are in here  [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)