# How can i have elispsis on my table cell without using max-width?

Tags: html, css

I have the following table

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Long name name name name name name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some shorter</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and my css

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

i needed to have elipsis on my table so that is why i used  `max-width: 100px;` together with `white-space: nowrap;`

But the problem here is that i need my td to have fixed with

```
td {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

if i do this than my td has fixed width but i lose the elipsis. Is there some way with which i can do this ?

Comment: what are you trying to do man with `ellipsis`?

Comment: I have long names so i can't show full name in tables - i show elipsis and on hover the full name...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)

Comment: No Peter i tried some of the rare answers there

Answer (score 0):

Use `table-layout:fixed;`

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Long name name name name name name Long name name name name name name Long name name name name name name Long name name name name name name Long name name name name name name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some shorter</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `-webkit-line-clamp`.
You can read more about the prerequisites [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp)

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Long name name name name name name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some shorter</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.Is there some other more generiw way ?