# Text overflow ellipsis only when content exceeds height not width limitations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out a way to show ellipses after text, but only when it reaches bounds of height not width, I know this can be done using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and `white-space: nowrap;` for width restricted elements, but can't figure it out for height.

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/c7bmyc4e/1/

Example code:

```
<p id="p-one">
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
</p>
```

---

```
<p id="p-two">
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
</p>

p{
        margin: 20px;
        background: red;
        height: 100px;
        width: 300px;
}

#p-two {
        margin: 100px 20px 20px 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802361/add-three-dots-in-a-multiline-span

Comment: See this article on Mobify: [multi-line ellipsis in pure CSS](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/). Certainly qualifies in the "*oh wow!*" category of brilliant use of CSS :)

Comment: It is because it doesn't support multiline text.

Comment: @FelipeAls Sweet, would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: @Ilja, you may post the code which worked for you, as an answer by checking "community wiki" before submitting and then accept it, so that will help other users.

Answer (score -2):

> For height ellipsis i have one **CSS** solution.

Suppose I have one **h2** element and I will apply css on that **h2**

```
 <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
 sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.</h2>
```

And this is **css** for height **ellipsis**

```
h2 {
  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 26*1.4*3; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size:26px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -webkit-line-clamp:3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**Note**: What is **-WebKit**

> WebKit is a HTML/CSS web browser rendering engine for Safari/Chrome.

**List of rendering engine for Web browser**

- **IE**

  - Engine: [Trident][2]
  - CSS-prefix: `-msie`
- **Firefox**

  - Engine: [Gecko][3]
  - CSS-prefix: `-moz`
- **Opera**

  - Engine: [Presto][4]
  - CSS-prefix: `-o`
- **Safari & Chrome**

  - Engine: [WebKit][5]
  - CSS-prefix: `-webkit`

> So for **Safari/Chrome**  use **-webkit** in **css** and for other
>   browser use **css-prefix** as mentioned above

**Example of above explanation** :   https://jsfiddle.net/c7bmyc4e/4/

Comment: @KevalBhatt interesting solution, would you like to post is as an answer?