# CSS text is overflowing icon

Tags: html, css, onsen-ui

Hey I have a clickable icon on the right and my text is overflowing it. How do I fix it ?

Codepen.io example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmPmba

> **image:**

[image]

> **code:**

```html
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="x in results" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <ons-row>
    <ons-col>
      {{ x.title }}
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col width="40px">
      <ons-icon icon="fa-ellipsis-h" size="22px" style="background-color:red"></ons-icon>
    </ons-col>
  </ons-row>
</ons-list-item>
```

Comment: Can you make a working demo with the output HTML & CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show dots ("...") in a span with hidden overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426275/how-can-i-show-dots-in-a-span-with-hidden-overflow)

Comment: @Thaillie http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmPmba

Answer (score 0):

You should set a width `width` property and then set `overflow:hidden`.
Like this

```
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="x in results" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <ons-row>
    <ons-col style="width:80px;overflow:hidden;">
      {{ x.title }}
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col width="40px">
      <ons-icon icon="fa-ellipsis-h" size="22px" style="background-color:red"></ons-icon>
    </ons-col>
  </ons-row>
</ons-list-item>
```

change the value of width according to your need.

Comment: That works correct, BUT I want the width to be full width. Screenwidth - 40px; Becuz sometimes users might want to rotate their screen..

Comment: you can use  % in that case... <ons-col style="width:75%;overflow:hidden;"> and <ons-col style="width:20%"> .

Comment: Again that won't be okay. Because I only want to display icon on the right so if I set 25% width user with ipad will see very long empty column

Comment: not getting provide a screen short if you can.. basically you shod test different width  for text and icon and then set position some thing like this..
<ons-col style="width:75%;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;left:0%;"> and <ons-col style="width:20%;position:absolute;left:76%;">