# Too long title slide the menu button to the right outside of the card

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with MuiCardHeader

```
<CardHeader
    disableTypography
    avatar={renderAvatar()}
    action={
        <IconButton onClick={toggleMenu}>
            <img src={MoreIcon} alt=""/>
        </IconButton>
    }
    title={
        <Typography noWrap variant="subtitle1">
            {data.name}
        </Typography>
    }
    subheader={
        <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="textSecondary">
            {data.children.items.length} items
        </Typography>
    }
/>
```

For some reason too long title or subtitle slide the menu button to the right outside the card.

How can I prevent it?

[image]

Result I need

[image]

Here is code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-paper-5d35h?file=/src/App.js

UPD: Solution

Add the following code

```
textOverflow: "ellipsis",
overflow: "hidden",
whiteSpace: "nowrap",
```

to `.MuiCardHeader-content` class

Thanks to everyone for help!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I will suggest you to check either overflow, if you want to hide the text and show the whole title in title html property. or you can make it break with word-break css

Comment: @Paulie_D https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-paper-5d35h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @MaximeGUILHEM I tried. Doesn't work

Comment: Thank for the code provided, just add `max-width: 70%;`on the class: `MuiCardHeader-content`

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426275/how-can-i-show-dots-in-a-span-with-hidden-overflow/11426653

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restrict the **parent** with `text-overflow: ellipsis`, `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap`

So in your case you just have to add `.MuiTypography-noWrap` to the **parent** `.MuiCardHeader-content`