# Limit text automatically according to div width using JQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net

Limit text automatically according to `<div>` width using JQuery or CSS

Input : This is my text and I want to limit.

```
.limit-text{
  width:300px;
}

<div class="limit-text">
   <span>This is my text and I want to limit.</span>
</div>
```

Output : This is my text and I wa....

Comment: Hello! :) You can refer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426275/how-can-i-show-dots-in-a-span-with-hidden-overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure CSS.

```
.limit-text{
  width:300px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

<div class="limit-text">
This is my text and I want to limit
</div>
```

For More Detailed Explanation Read This [Tweet](https://twitter.com/denicmarko/status/1308348731708903424) By @denicmarko on Twitter