# *ngIf to check length of title

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a response from an API where I get back titles. If the title is longer than a certain amount of characters, the card in which the title is displayed grows in height, causing the card to be larger than its siblings in the same row. I want to find a way to trim the title and add '...' at the end of the title so that the title only takes up one line and all cards are the same size.

I am able to display the title if the length is less than 23, but I am unsure of how to format longer titles so that they are 22 characters with '...' added at the end.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div *ngIf="game.title.length < 23; Dont know what to put here"> 
      <h5 class="card-title">{{game.title}}</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: How about using CSS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426275/how-can-i-show-dots-in-a-span-with-hidden-overflow

Comment: Thanks, that link was also a great help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use css instead. On your div you should add a class such as .overflow-ellipse

`.overflow-ellipse {   white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }`

Otherwise you can use substring if you want a specific char count.. but that's not as flexible as the css path https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, just thought it might be easier to do it in ng. I've never heard of 'ellipsis'.