# If screen size is mobile size ,replace the end of the HTML text with two dots

Tags: html, css

How can I change the end of a HTML text and replace it with two dots , if resolution is for mobile or tablet size? And without changing the size of the buttons (all buttons same size). Thanks
i.e. Stackoverflow --> Stack..

```css
.flex-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;

}

.flex-buttons > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-buttons">
  <div>Stackoverflow12345</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>      
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overflow:hidden dots at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486563/overflowhidden-dots-at-the-end) and [How can I show dots (“…”) in a span with hidden overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426275/how-can-i-show-dots-in-a-span-with-hidden-overflow)

Comment: This is not for screen size or mobile size, this is just a function how to add dots at the end of a text..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden;` `white-space: nowrap;` in conjuntion with `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, the later displays the `...` where text overflow is present on the content.

```css
.flex-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.flex-buttons > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-buttons">
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>      
  <div>Stackoverflow</div>
</div>
```