# Simple way to truncate text

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overflow:hidden dots at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486563/overflowhidden-dots-at-the-end)

I'm coding a simple chat webapp, and I want to truncate the name of each participant. For instance, instead of:

```
Miguel de Unamuno: 03:14 
    Homo sum, nihil homini alienum puto
```

I want:

```
Miguel de U...: 03:14 
    Homo sum, nihil homini alienum puto
```

I see I could do this with JS, but seems like it should be quite a common thing, so I'm sure there is a simple way to do this with HTML+CSS I am not being able to find. Is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ellipsis`

**HTML**

```
<span>Miguel de Unamuno:</span> 03:14 
<p> Homo sum, nihil homini alienum puto</p>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 95px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; display:inline-block
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jcAGs/)**

Answer (score 3):

see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/45Fc6/

try this css:

```
.ellipsis-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis` to truncate the text:

```
div {
    width: 50px;

    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;

    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zn7tY/1/**