# Putting (...) at the end of a text after a specific number of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field. And I want that it shows the (...) at the end of my text  when I hit a specific number of characters.

I heard something about `Substring` but I don't know how to use it.

Here is my Input field. The `data-limit` shows at which point the text is to long.

```
    <input class="controlinput" id="metadescription" data-limit="156"  data-class=".metadescription" type="text" >
```

And here is where the text will display when I type it in the input field.

```
<span class="metadescription"> </span>
```

Comment: Do you want the (...) to be shown in the `<span class="metadescription"> </span>` or the `input` field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overflow:hidden dots at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486563/overflowhidden-dots-at-the-end)

Comment: it should display in the span

Comment: @Mahi linked question is regarding css and overflow (ie fit to box) rather than specific character limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('yourInput').addEventListener('input', function(){
  var val = document.getElementById('yourInput').value
  if(val.length === 156){
    document.getElementById('yourInput').value = val + '(...)';
  }
})
```

if you add an eventhandler for change event of the input field you can check how long is the added string and if it reaches the given length you can add the string you want to

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a623p30u/

Comment: Not 100% working. Once you reach the 156 limit, it would then be 161 and the input would accept characters to be appended after (...) because of the explicit check of 156.

Comment: you are right, but i was lazy to solve the whole problem, i think its a good way to start

Comment: yes, it is not working out of box, you need to change it a little bit to match your needs

Comment: could you please post your changes?

Comment: document.getElementById('#metadescription').addEventListener('change', function(){
  var val = document.getElementById('#metadescription').value
  if(val.length === 156){document.getElementById('#metadescription').value + '(...)'}
})

Comment: it is because you assign a new value to nothing, i change my answer

Comment: i!ve updated my answer with a jsfiddle link, for me it was working like this

Answer (score 0):

sources:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

```
var input = $('.controlinput');
var inputLength = input.val().length
var maxLength = input.data('limit');
var mustTruncate = inputLength > maxLength;
if(mustTruncate){
  var truncatedValue = input.val().substring(0, maxLength) + "(...)";
  var label = $("."+input.data("class"));
  label.html(truncatedValue);
}
```