# How to change the styles and to expand cropped text with CSS only after button click?

Tags: html, css

I want to create some HTML table/list/whatever with items like:

```
Some very long te... ▶
Some very long te... ▶
Some very long te... ▶
```

and when I click on some `▶` (2nd in the example) to get:

```
Some very long te... ▶
Some very long text is here
 and here, and more and more
Some very long te... ▶
```

and to achieve it with CSS only, without Javascript. Is it possible? How to do it? Some example?

IMHO goals could be reduced, maybe to:

- expand cropped text
- change styles of the container (?)

Comment: Try using the :active element of css for changing the width on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get close with just CSS however the full text is shown on hover rather than on click of the `▶`.

```css
ul {width:150px; margin:0; padding:0; }
li {margin:0; padding:0 10px 0 0; display:block; position:relative; white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;}
li:after {content:"▶";position:absolute; right:0;}
li:hover {white-space: normal;
  overflow: auto;}
li:hover:after {display:none;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Some very long text is here
 and here, and more and more.</li>
 <li>Some very long text is here
 and here, and more and more.</li>
 <li>Some very long text is here
 and here, and more and more.</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` for the dots and then on the button-click add a class that makes the container wider. As seen here: [Overflow:hidden dots at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486563/overflowhidden-dots-at-the-end)

In that case the only Javascript you need is to add (and maybe remove) the class. Here's a thread explaining the Javascript part: [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Doing it completley without Javascript i don't think is possible since you need it the listen to the button-click.